# Updating List<T> in MemoryCache on .NET Core

Tags: c#, memorycache

I need to store and update List in MemoryCache. Every transaction hitting my WEB.API will add a record to this List, and every 1 min the list will be dumped into database and removed from cache.

My issue is concurrency and avoiding dirty reads/writes. I also need to write to this list very quickly so my transaction is not delayed.

```
// get list in cache
List<MyObj> stat = cache.Get<List<MyObj>>(key);

if (stat == null)
  stat = new List<MyObj>() { new MyObj() { SomeKey = SomeVal } };
else
  stat.Add(new MyObj() { SomeKey = SomeVal });

// by this time another thread could modify the cached object, so my current object is not good anymore
cache.Set<List<MyObj>>(key, stat);
```

Comment: Maybe [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8) would suit better your needs? Another options is [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: You'll need a `lock` around **all** accesses of that `List` if you continue to use `List<T>` since `List<T>` is not thread-safe.

Comment: I agree with @abatishchev. `BlockingCollection` or `ConcurrentQueue` is likely what you want.

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1362995/559144

Comment: @mjwills even though `MemoryCache` is thread-safe, this particular usage of it is not. Multiple threads could get `stat == null` for the same `key` in the time it takes to create a `new List`.

Comment: That is correct @PatrickRoberts. The OP should thus likely not use a `MemoryCache` at all - and just use a `static` `ConcurrentQueue`.

Comment: Thanks All. I have decided to implement a Singleton of BlockingCollection instead of using MemoryCache. This is working for me.

Comment: Please post a sketch or some PoC of what you've ended up with (and accept as an answer), this will help others!