# Is it safe to add and remove items from a List object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Assume we have multiple threads and a public `List` that is responsible to hold real-time data. We have some thread that is responsible to add data to list object. Another thread is responsible to get data from list object and then remove the items from top.

Question: Is it safe to remove from begin of a `List` and simultaneously add data to end of list in separate threads? How `List` object is implemented?

Comment: You can use lock. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362995/properly-locking-a-listt-in-multithreaded-scenarios

Comment: No it's not tread safe, base on what you want to implement checkout concurrent collections, especially `ConcurrentQueue<T>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @SelimYıldız I mean is it implemented in list object or we have to it handy?

Comment: Related: [List<T> thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020486/listt-thread-safety)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8#thread-safety):

> Public static members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are **not guaranteed** to be thread safe.
>
> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it's being read.

So, if your collection can be modified by some of the threads - you need to [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) it on write **and** read operations.

The docs also points you to another solution:

> For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8) namespace.

Like [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8), for example. Use `.Enqueue(obj)` to insert it at the end of the queue and `TryDequeue(out obj)` to get it from the top of the queue.

Comment: Thanks. Does Dequeue remove completely from ConcurrentQueue and reduce the size of object?

Comment: "So, if you lock your collection while you remove elements from it - you are ok." This is a bit misleading. The lock has to be used when accessing the list independent what the threads do. If you use a read write lock you could be more efficient, but the reading threads still need a lock too

Comment: @HOPE, yes, `TryDequeue` removes element from queue. There is also a `TryPeek`, which just "peek" an element from top without removal.

Comment: @Voo, agreed. I rephrased this to be less misleading.

Comment: Thanks. IProducerConsumerCollection<T> is a good choose. I've use it now :) .

Answer (score 3):

List is not thread safe.

The problem you're solving looks like a producer-consumer problem, so what you need is a collection which implements [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.iproducerconsumercollection-1?view=netcore-3.1):

- [`System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netcore-3.1)
- [`System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netcore-3.1)
- [`System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1?view=netcore-3.1)

If you also need bounded buffer (only allow certain amount of items in the collection at all time), you could use [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netcore-3.1), with any of the above as inner collection.

Comment: Thanks. IProducerConsumerCollection<T> is a good choose. I've use it now :) .